AKS - Microsoft Entra ID authentication with Azure RBAC
I have an AKS in an Azure Subscription. AKS version is 1.26.x. Not old. And I have gone into Cluster Configuration and chose "Microsoft Entra ID authentication with Azure RBAC". and not "Microsoft Entra ID authentication with Kubernetes RBAC". It was initially set to Local account with Kubernetes.
Now, I want to know how to control access to the AKS cluster. I have developers who need to be able to pull az aks creds and only kubectl get  and kubectl logs and kubectl events. I don't want them to create or delete any deployments or any secrets. But they can read.
Some people want to be able to az get creds and also create deployments. I want to know how I can manage these 2 groups of people and by what Roles. Appreciate any insight.
I am also confused about why we need kubelogin, it sounds like If i am using AKS version > 1.24, we use kubelogin automatically. what does this mean? does this mean az aks get-credentials is not to be used?
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac


Create Groups for Users and
Developers Group: For users needing read-only access.
Ops Team Group: For users needing deployment rights. Use the Azure portal or Azure CLI to assign roles to these groups- az role assignment create --assignee <developers-group-object-id> --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" --scope <aks-cluster-resource-id> or az role assignment create --assignee <ops-team-group-object-id> --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Contributor" --scope <aks-cluster-resource-id> Retrieve credentials to set up kubectl for both groups using Azure AD for authentication.

will adding "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader"  to usersanddevgrp be enough to az aks get-creds and kubect get all, and kubectl logs on a pod. and also do they need to run the kubelogin after az aks get-creds?

Adding the Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader role to the usersanddevgrp will be sufficient for the members of this group to perform actions such as using az aks get-credentials, kubectl get all, and kubectl logs for pods. This role grants read-only access across the AKS cluster, which includes listing and viewing resources as well as accessing logs.

To manage access to your AKS cluster using Microsoft Entra ID with Azure RBAC, you'll need to assign appropriate roles to different user groups based on their access requirements
First, create groups in Azure Active Directory (AAD) for different user categories if not already available.
Create a Group for Developers (Read-Only Access)
az ad group create --display-name "AKS-Developers" --mail-nickname "aksdevelopers"


Create a Group for Ops Team (Create/Manage Deployments)
az ad group create --display-name "AKS-Ops" --mail-nickname "aksops"


Assign appropriate built-in RBAC roles to these groups.
Assign RBAC Reader Role to Developers Group
az role assignment create --assignee <developers-group-object-id> --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" --scope /subscriptions/<Subscription-ID>/resourcegroups/<Resource-Group>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/<Cluster-Name>


Assign RBAC Contributor Role to Ops Team Group if required
az role assignment create --assignee <ops-team-group-object-id> --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Contributor" --scope /subscriptions/<Subscription-ID>/resourcegroups/<Resource-Group>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/<Cluster-Name>

Now if your members are already added in the group then this step is not required, if creating new group and you are adding members then-
az ad group member add --group 'AKS-Developers' --member-id <User-Object-ID>

How to get the user object id?
az ad user list --query "[].{name: displayName, objectId: objectId}"

if you know the name, then
az ad user list --query "[?contains(displayName, 'NameOfThePerson')].{name: displayName, objectId: objectId}"

Set up kubectl to use Azure AD for authentication by retrieving credentials with kubelogin.
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <Resource-Group> --name <Cluster-Name> --use-kubelogin

This command configures your kubeconfig automatically to use kubelogin for Azure AD authentication, simplifying the login process and enabling seamless token refresh.
Done.  Verify Access Control-
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

or
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces=true


